# How to rename or change schema name in IBM Informix Database for All Tables

Tags: informix

I have created a database as "neura_test_dev" and schema as "neura_test_dev".

Now I have renamed database name as "neura_name_change_dev" by issuing the command below:

```sql
RENAME DATABASE neura_test_dev TO neura_name_change_dev;
```

**How can I change the schema name in an Informix database? Please guide.**

NOTE: I need to change or rename all tables.

Answer (score 1):

For Informix servers the schema name is also known as the table (or view or other object) owner. It is not possible to change the owner of a table using a command such as RENAME TABLE.

If the database is not too large then one option could be to use the `dbexport` command (with -ss option) to export the database to a directory. In that directory will be the database schema sql file which could be edited to change the existing owner references to the new owner/schema name. The owner name should appear within double quotes "" and ensure that all references are changed as some lines may use the owner name multiple times. Having edited the file the database would then be dropped in the Informix server and imported using the `dbimport` command.

As with most operations of this nature it is a good practice to take a backup of the Informix server prior to dropping and recreating the database in case the results are not as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon. I will follow this option.